# How to model and query Office Hours in MongoDB (dates, timezones, dst)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, timezone, momentjs

Weekly Office Hours: mon,wed,fri  10am->11:45am

I want to track office hours for a collection of people.  When their hours start, I want to `setSign('open')`.  When they end, `setSign('closed')`

This model is clearly broken.  How to model and query while respecting timezones in MongoDB is the question.

```
people.find({});
[{
  name: 'hank',
  days: [1,3,5], // mon,wed,fri
  start: '08:00',
  end: '17:00,
  lastSign: 'new',
}]
```

So, every 5 minutes, I run a query:

```
var hoursNowOpen = people.find({
  lastSign: { $ne: 'open' },
  ????
});

// Set to open
hoursNowOpen.forEach(function(person) { person.setSign('open');});

// Mark we set the sign to open
var ids = hoursNowOpen.map(function(person) { return person._id;});
people.update({_id: {$in: ids}}, { lastSign: 'open' });
```

I hate timezones and dst so much.  Thanks for any help!

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing missing from your model is a time zone identifier, such as `America/New_York`, or `Asia/Tokyo` - assuming each person might be in a different time zone.  If they're all in the same time zone, then you just need to know that time zone in your application logic.

However, this won't help you *query*.  For that, you'd have to project each *occurrence* to a set of UTC-based date+time values.  There's always a tradeoff.  If you have relatively few people, you might just load them all, and test the current date against the rules.

If you have lots of people, then you will certainly need to project each occurrence periodically, so that you can do a simple range query against the current UTC time to see who is open.